# When to address managed heap fragmentation

Tags: .net, caching, heap-fragmentation

I was reading a [blog entry](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/a-base-class-which-implements-inotifypropertychanged/) by Josh Smith where he used a cache mechanism in order to "reduce managed heap fragmentation". His caching reduces the number of short-lived objects being created at the cost of slightly slower execution speed.

How much of a problem is managed heap fragmentation in a managed language like C#? How can you diagnose if it's an issue? In what situations would you typically need to address it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When

Not too quickly. It is generally very cheap to have short lived objects. For a cache to be profitable  there would have to be (very) many candiadates and they should live long enough to make it to the next generation.

> How can you diagnose if it's an issue?

With a Profiler. I'm not so sure the author of the article  did that.

> How much of a problem is managed heap fragmentation in a managed language like C#?

As far as I know it is rare. .NET has a compacting Garbage collector, that prevents most forms of fragmentation. There are issues with the Large Object Heap sometimes.

---

Edit:

When you go through the comments below the article you will find that someone measured it and found the cache to be a lot slower than creating new eventargs each time.

**Conclusion:** Measure before you start optimizing. This was not a good idea/example.

Comment: +1. Can't stand it when people spend time "optimizing" without good cause.

Comment: Yes--the caching is at the expense of execution speed.

Comment: ... but if it prevents the GC from collecting the LOH **all the time**, it for sure can pay of

Comment: @user492238 - No, EventArgs are way too small for the LOH.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I don't claim the eventargs are on LOH? I'd say caching can pay off in situations where the GC is not optimized for. Often this is related to LOH. Take 1 Mill LOH objects (plain arrays) and do some computation in a loop. I don't need a profiler to know in advance, that reusing them is MUCH better performance wise than relying on the GC to reclaim them from the LOH. (Yes, in general we should use profilers though ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are dealing with 10K+ small short-lived objects per second, it should not be an issue at all on a modern computer with reasonable amount of RAM.

So first you should run the code in all reasonable scenarios and if it's fast enough - don't worry about it.

If you are not happy with the speed, you see that code sometime 'chokes' or a just curious, you can monitor various .NET Memory stats (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx) in Performance Monitor app (comes as part of Windows). Specifically you are interested in % Time in GC.

redgate ANTS profiler also monitors these stats.

Comment: Found an article on Perfmon and Garbage Collection http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/03/31/60938.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Managed heap fragmentation is usually because of pinning of objects. Objects get pinned when managed code passes the object pointer to the native code and the object cannot be moved because the reference is passed to the native code. This is very common when there is a lot of I/O activities. Like mentioned above it usually happens only in LOH.

Here is an example of [Fragmentation in Gen0 Heap](http://blogs.msdn.com/hkrishna/archive/2010/02/28/debugging-fragmentation-in-gen0-heap.aspx)

Comment: Since objects on the LOH are not moved at all, it does not make any difference, if they are pinned as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other answers given here I state: yes, one should take care of fragmentation! It does not only apply to managed heaps but to all apps handling (at least)

- many "large" ressources in
- a heavy allocation pattern.

Since the LOB does not get compacted, it - over time - most probably will get fragmented as soon as the size and number of the objects exceed a certain value (which relates to the overall max heapsize available). If it does, the only safe way is to limit the number of instantly holded references to those objects. A cache (pool) would only help, if objects pooled can be reused. Sometimes, if these ressources are made of arrays of varying length f.e., they might not be reusable easily. So pooling may not help much here.

How to detect it? When ever there is large pressure on the LOB heap. How to find out it is? Use the .NET performance counter "Collection Count Gen 0...2" at the same time. If too many large objects are allocated from the LOB, all counters will evolve identically. Meaning, basically all collections are *expensive* generation 2 collections. In that case, there should something be done.

Regarding smaller objects, I would let the GC do all the work in Gen 0 collections and dont worry.

Comment: thanks for the downvote. please leave a comment with some reasoning so that the answer can be improved and others can profit from your experience!